# How to copy header row to new csv in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I can't seem to figure out how to copy my header row from master to matched... I need to grab the first row in my master csv and write it first in matched, then write the remaining lines if they match the criteria...

```
with open('master.csv', 'r') as master, open('match.csv', 'w') as matched:
    for line in master:
            if any(city in line.split('","')[5] for city in citys) and \
            any(state in line.split('","')[6] for state in states) and \
            not any(category in line.split('","')[2] for category in categorys):
                matched.write(line)
```

Please help. I am new to python and don't know how to use pandas or anything else...

Comment: What's the need for the single-double-comma-single-double pattern?  Is that so that it ignores commas embedded within quotes?

Comment: Do you need the "for city in citys"? You are only running the IF statement on one line at a time, right?

Comment: @ScottEdwards2000 The single-double-comma-single-double pattern is due to the format of my csv

Comment: ah, ok - could you elaborate on the specific format of your csv that requires that pattern?  just haven't seen it before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just consume the first line of the file to read and write it back in the file to be written:

```
with open('master.csv', 'r') as master, open('match.csv', 'w') as matched:
    matched.write(next(master)) # can't use readline when iterating on the file afterwards
```

Seems that you really need `csv` module, though, for the rest. I'll edit my answer to attempt something in that direction

With the `csv` module, no need for those unsafe `split`. Comma is the default separator and quotes are also handled properly. So I'd just write:

```
import csv
with open('master.csv', 'r') as master, open('match.csv', 'w') as matched:
    cr = csv.reader(master)
    cw = csv.writer(matched)
    cw.writerow(next(cr))  # copy title

    for row in cr:  # iterate on the rows, already organized as lists
        if any(city in row[5] for city in citys) and \
        any(state in row[6] for state in states) and \
        not any(category in row[2] for category in categorys):
            cw.writerow(row)
```

BTW your filter checks that `city` is contained in `row[5]`, but maybe you'd like an exact match. Ex: `"York"` would match `"New York"`, which is probably not what you want. So my proposal would be using `in` to check if the string is in the list of strings, for each criterion:

```
import csv
with open('master.csv', 'r') as master, open('match.csv', 'w') as matched:
    cr = csv.reader(master)
    cw = csv.writer(matched)
    cw.writerow(next(cr))  # copy title
    for row in cr:
        if row[5] in citys and row[6] in states and not row[2] in categorys:
           cw.writerow(row)
```

which can be even bettered using *generator comprehension* and write all lines at once:

```
import csv
with open('master.csv', 'r') as master, open('match.csv', 'w') as matched:
    cr = csv.reader(master)
    cw = csv.writer(matched)
    cw.writerow(next(cr))  # copy title
    cw.writerows(row for row in cr if row[5] in citys and row[6] in states and not row[2] in categorys)
```

note that `citys`, `states`, and `categorys` would be better as `set`s rather than `list`s so lookup algorithm is much faster (you didn't provide that information)

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. I keep getting this error after adding your code in...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yelpscrape.py", line 51, in <module>
    cw.writerow(next(cr))  # copy title
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: Nevermind. I got it working. Didn't piece it in quite right. I believe it's working now. Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to think too hard about how the line-producing iterator works, oOne straightforward way to do it is to treat the first line special:

```
with open('master.csv', 'r') as master, open('match.csv', 'w') as matched:
    first_line = True
    for line in master:
            if first_line or (any(city in line.split('","')[5] for city in citys) and \
            any(state in line.split('","')[6] for state in states) and \
            not any(category in line.split('","')[2] for category in categorys)):
                matched.write(line)
            first_line = False
```